# C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin IDE problem - doesn't detect externally changed source file

Tags: delphi, ide

I have a main form and a couple of GUI component files in my project. When I have a lot of editing to do, I prefer to do it outside the RAD Studio IDE (using Vim, if you wondered...).
If I make a change and go back to the IDE, it should detect that the file has been changed externally and ask me to reload it. This works as expected on all the files bar one of the component C++ files, on which it NEVER works!
This is a major pain as I can make a change and when I later do a build, the out-of-date IDE version is saved, overwriting the changes I made with Vim.
Does anyone know a) why it happens, and b) why to only one file?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that the mentioned file is a part of some package that is only included into your application. In order for changes to take effect in your application you would either have to rebuild the said package or making sure that the mentioned file is included in your application individually.

Comment: Thanks Warrior.  I did create the file as part of a package, but it was included in the project.  However the other file in the same package didn't experience this problem.  As Mañuel would say, ¿Qué?  I was also having other problems with the package, where the sizing and positioning of controls would bear no resemblance to the design in the IDE so I have dispensed with the package approach, which seems to have solved the problem.  Thanks again.